# How to get the href of a link using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jquery code:

```
$(function(){                              
   $('#note_pag a').click(function(){      
    alert('click');                
    return false;                          
   });                                     
});
```

and this is the html code:

```
<div id="note_pag">                               
  <ul>                                            
    <li><a href="1">1</a></li>                    
    <li><a href="2">2</a></li>                    
    <li><a href="3">3</a></li>                    
    <li><a href="4">4</a></li>                    
  </ul>                                           
</div>
```

my question is: how can i get the href of the link clicked from the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the event handler, `this` is a reference to the element clicked. You can then use that DOM element to build a jQuery selection, and then use the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) function to get the value of the `href` attribute:

```
$(function(){                              
   $('#note_pag a').click(function(){      
    alert('cliccato link');  
    alert($(this).attr('href'));              
    return false;                          
   });                                     
});
```

Comment: `$(this).prop('href')` is absolutely pointless - `this.href` works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){                              
   $('#note_pag a').click(function(){      
    alert($(this).attr('href'));                
    return false;                          
   });                                     
});
```

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/pHhw5/