# use jquery to show/hide a div based on link href

Tags: jquery

I currently have part of this working:

```
$('#marketing_button').click(function() {
        $('#marketing').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
        });
    });
```

If I click a element with id marketing_button, then it will show the marketing div.

I am setting up a basic show/hide for a set of divs and buttons.  I have 5 hrefs and 5 divs.  Each href has its own id, but I feel like there is a easier way to do this than copying this code 5 times.

Also I need to hide the other divs when a new one is clicked.

structure looks like:

```
<a href="marketing" id="marketing_button">MArketing</a>
<a href="processing" id="processing_button">Processing</a>
<a href="compliance" id="compliance_button">Compliance</a>
...
<div id="services">
<div id"marketing"></div>
<div id"processing"></div>
<div id"compliance"></div>
...
</div>
```

So here are the specific questions:  how do I access the href so that I don't need to repeat the code 5 times,

how do I close the visible div and fade in the new one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the href of a link using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818705/how-to-get-the-href-of-a-link-using-jquery)

Answer (score 6):

In order to do this generically you'll need a way of finding all of the anchors to which you want to apply this function.  The simplest way is to add a common class to them.

```
<a href="marketing" id="marketing_button" class="abutton">MArketing</a>
<a href="processing" id="processing_button" class="abutton">Processing</a>
<a href="compliance" id="compliance_button" class="abutton">Compliance</a>
```

Now that you can access the relevant anchors you can do the following

```
$('a.abutton').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
  $(id).fadeIn('slow', function () {
    // Animation complete
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of possible solutions. Without knowing all the details, I would put a wrapping div with a class. When the link is clicked, it toggles its sibling div.